# Issue getting commands made in CrudRepository to translate into a function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, crud

My issue lies with the fact that a function that I made that should work, does not. CRUD is an extension that uses a specific naming convention to create functions, and I can't seem to use it correctly.

```
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

//JPA creates this query findBy{variable name}
User findByEmail(String email);

Iterable<User> findAllByTeamId(String TeamId);//WHERE THE ISSUE SEEMS TO LIE

User findBySlackIdAndTeamId(String slackId, String teamId);

User findByResetToken(String resetToken);
   }
```

Below is the code for the class that it goes into, UserService.java, which cannot compile as a result of an issue with not reading findAllByTeamId() correctly. What am I doing wrong here? Which of these two codes need o change for this to function correctly?

```
    @Service
    public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public User saveUser(User user)
{
    return userRepository.save(user);   //Returns the user it saves?

}

//CREATE GETUSERSBYTEAMID -- WHERE THE ISSUE SEEMS TO LIE
public List<User> findAllByTeamId(String id)
{
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterable<User> usersIterable = userRepository.findAllByTeamId(id);
    usersIterable.forEach(users::add);
    return users;

}


public List<User> getAllUsers()
{
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterable<User> usersIterable = userRepository.findAll();
    usersIterable.forEach(users::add);
    return users;

}

public User findByEmail(String email)
{
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    return user;
}

public User findBySlackIdAndTeamId(String slackId, String teamId)
{
    User user = userRepository.findBySlackIdAndTeamId(slackId, teamId);
    return user;
}

public User findByResetToken(String resetToken)
{
    return userRepository.findByResetToken(resetToken);
}
    }
```

Comment: Welcome.  You should consider also including a stacktrace of the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

I tried to copy-paste your code in my project and it's compiling without error. Can you please provide User class and exception stacktrace?

BTW, parameter of the method findAllByTeamId has capitalize first letter. :)

```
Iterable<User> findAllByTeamId(String TeamId);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put them to different packages, please make sure findAllByTeamId is public method.